# VBA 1004 error - Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am inserting the following INDEX MATCH formula into a set of cells using VBA.

```
        cell2.FormulaArray = _
"=INDEX('[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!AK:AK, _ 
    MATCH(1,('[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!$A:$A = A " & value & ")* _
('[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!$B:$B=""Total""),0))*1000"
```

When this runs, I encounter an error 1004 - "Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class"

I'm fairly certain it has something to do with referencing a workbook outside of the current as it works fine when I INDEX MATCH inside the same workbook.

The condensed version of the formula (for reading clarity) is the following -

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!AK:AK, MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A:A = A5)*(Sheet2!B:B="Total"),0))
```

Then in vba -

```
cell2.FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C, MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A:A = A5)*(Sheet2!B:B=""Total""),0))"
```

Comment: `FormulaArray` is limited to 255 characters. This has been discussed many times here. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, this is down to a limitation of the length of formula you can use in VBA with `FormulaArray`. Here, you can probably simply use a non-array version:

```
cell2.Formula = _
"=LOOKUP(2,1/('[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!$A:$A=A" & Value & _
")*('[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!$B:$B=""Total"")," & _
"'[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!AK:AK)*1000"
```

though this will return the last matching item rather than the first, if you have multiple rows matching your criteria.

Comment: Incredible stuff. Works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**How to enter `FormulaArray` with over 255 characters using VBA**

It seems that, in this case, there was an alternate *Standard Formula* that complied with the requirements of the original `FormulaArray`. However, there might be cases for which there is not an alternate formula.
For those cases, I have the following *method to enter `FormulaArray` with over 255 characters using VBA*.

Most of the time when a `FormulaArray` is longer than 255 characters is due to the length of the `references` it contains, as they may relate to long constant arrays, external workbooks with large names *(like in this case)* or worksheets with large names *(also in this case)*. The method consist in replacing these long strings with shorter ones, however in order for the `FormulaArray` *(after replacement)* to be accepted as a `FormulaArray` those shorter strings need to also represent valid `references`.

As per the above, there could be, at least, three situations with long `references`:

1. Long constant arrays: In these cases use `Defined Names` as described here

https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

2. `Workbooks` with large names and
3. `Worksheets` with large names

For cases 2 and 3 same method applies: The use of short `references` pointing to a *temporary* `Worksheet` as temporary replacement.

**Applying the method to this case:**

*Original* `FormulaArray`: use variable `sFmlArray` to hold the formula

```
Dim sFmlArray As String
sFmlArray = "=INDEX('[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!AK:AK," & _
    "MATCH(1,('[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!$A:$A = A" & bVal & ") * " & _
    "('[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!$B:$B=""Total""),0)) * 1000"
```

I suggest the use of variables to hold the names of the workbook and worksheet in order to avoid having to write them several times.

```
Dim sFmlRng as string
sFmlRng = "'[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!"
```

Replace the names of the workbook and worksheet in the `FormulaArray` with the corresponding variable:

```
sFmlAry = "=INDEX(" & sFmlRng & "AK:AK," & _
    "MATCH(1,(" & sFmlRng & "$A:$A = A" & bVal & ") * " & _
    "(" & sFmlRng & "$B:$B=""Total""),0)) * 1000"
```

Assuming we want to enter this long `FormulaArray` in the range `D7:D10`, let’s assign it to a variable

```
Dim rFmlAry as Range
Set rFmlAry = ActiveSheet.Range("D7:D10")
```

Use the function below to add the *temporary* worksheet. This function also provides the *temporary* `reference` to be used as replacement in the `FormulaArray`

```
Function WshTmp_Add(rFmlAry As Range, sFmlRngTmp As String) As Worksheet
    sFmlRngTmp = "@Tmp"
    With rFmlAry.Worksheet.Parent
        On Error Resume Next
        .Worksheets(sFmlRngTmp).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set WshTmp_Add = .Worksheets.Add(Before:=.Worksheets(1))
    End With
    WshTmp_Add.Name = sFmlRngTmp
    WshTmp_Add.Tab.Color = 255
    sFmlRngTmp = "'" & sFmlRngTmp & "'!"
    Application.Goto rFmlAry
End Function
```

Replace, in the `FormulaArray`, the long references with the shorter one and enter the *temporary* `FormulaArray` in the `rFmlAry` range

```
sFmlAryTmp = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(sFmlAry, sFmlRng, sFmlRngTmp)
rFmlAry.FormulaArray = sFmlAryTmp
```

With the `FormulaArray` in place, replace the *temporary* short `references` with the original long ones

```
rFmlAry.Replace What:=sFmlRngTmp, Replacement:=sFmlRng, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Finally delete the *temporary* `Worksheet`

This is the entire procedure *(as a test, added few lines at the end to validate the result)*

```
Sub FormulaArray_Over255Chr()
Dim rFmlAry As Range, sFmlAry As String, bVal As Byte

Dim WshTmp As Worksheet, sFmlAryTmp As String
Dim sFmlRng As String, sFmlRngTmp As String
Dim blAppDisplayAlerts As Boolean
    blAppDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts

    Rem Set Ranges & Values
    bVal = 5
    Set rFmlAry = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D5")

    Rem Define External Reference Variable
    sFmlRng = "'[08 Debt Comparison & Provision Report.xlsx]Details by Bus Area &  Location'!"

    Rem Define FormulaArray (Original) - with References as Variables
    sFmlAry = "=INDEX(" & sFmlRng & "AK:AK," & _
        "MATCH(1,(" & sFmlRng & "$A:$A = A" & bVal & ") * " & _
        "(" & sFmlRng & "$B:$B=""Total""),0)) * 1000"

    Rem Set Range to Enter FormulaArray
    Set rFmlAry = ActiveSheet.Range("D7:D10")

    Rem Add Temporary Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set WshTmp = WshTmp_Add(rFmlAry, sFmlRngTmp)

    Rem Set Temporary FormulaArray - Replace long references
    sFmlAryTmp = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(sFmlAry, sFmlRng, sFmlRngTmp)

    Rem Enter Temporary FormulaArray
    rFmlAry.FormulaArray = sFmlAryTmp

    Rem Set FormulaArray (Original) - Replace short references in situ
    rFmlAry.Replace What:=sFmlRngTmp, Replacement:=sFmlRng, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    Rem Delete Temporary Worksheet
    WshTmp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = blAppDisplayAlerts

' ****************************************************************
' Lines for TESTING - Resulting FormulaArray - REMOVED when final
' ****************************************************************
    Rem Validate FormulaArray
    Debug.Print String(3, vbLf)
    Debug.Print "FormulaArray in Range: "
    Debug.Print rFmlAry.Cells(1).FormulaArray
    Debug.Print "FormulaArray VBA: "
    Debug.Print sFmlAry
    If rFmlAry.Cells(1).FormulaArray = sFmlAry Then
        MsgBox "FormulaArray with +255 entered successfully" & vbLf & _
            vbLf & rFmlAry.Cells(1).FormulaArray
    Else
        MsgBox "Something did not worked!" & vbLf & _
            vbLf & "Review formulas printed in the Immediate Window"
            SendKeys "^g": Stop
    End If
' ****************************************************************

End Sub
```