# Shortening the formula array in VBA to be shorter than 255 characters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have some Formula Array similar to the one below, just with longer table names in the VBA, causing it to exceed 255 characters by 20-30 characters. (The one below is less than 200 characters)

`"= IFERROR(Index(INDIRECT(""myTable[Inventory]""), Match(1, (""Vans"" = INDIRECT( ""myTable[Brand]""))*(""Shoes"" = INDIRECT(""myTable[Product]""),0))), NA())"`

I can't figure out how to shorten the Formula Array below 255 characters. Useful References:

- [VBA 1004 error - Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886821/vba-1004-error-unable-to-set-the-formulaarray-property-of-the-range-class)
- http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/

Comment: That formula already is less than 255 characters.  You have `"` where you need `""` around `Vans` and `Shoes`

Comment: @ScottCraner I have a formula similar to this one, just with longer table names causing it to exceed 255 characters. And I'll update the post to fix ```"``` around ```Vans``` and ```Shoes```

Comment: Then update it to represent that. This is not even close to 200 characters

Comment: You may a) assign names via Names Manager:  e.g. `inv` referring  to  `=INDIRECT("MyTable[Inventory]")` and b) re-use each tabular named reference in the abbreviated formula like `"= IFERROR(Index(inv, Match(...` @MJ

Comment: Is there any other way? Like creating a dummy function?

Comment: Something along these lines: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/